# Property "Craft\WebApp.assetUpload" is not defined

Tags: error-templates

I came across error Property "Craft\WebApp.assetUpload" is not defined, when registering users from front end. Is this a bug or missing config param?

I have used the example on craft website:
https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/user-registration-form

The Actual template used is:

```
<h1>Membership Registration</h1>

<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8">

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/saveUser">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="">

    {% macro errorList(errors) %}
        {% if errors %}
            <ul class="errors">
                {% for error in errors %}
                    <li>{{ error }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    {% endmacro %}

    {% from _self import errorList %}

    <h3><label for="username">Username</label></h3>
    <input id="username" type="text" name="username"
    {%- if account is defined %} value="{{ account.username }}"{% endif -%}>

    {% if account is defined %}
        {{ errorList(account.getErrors('username')) }}
    {% endif %}

    <h3><label for="email">Email</label></h3>
    <input id="email" type="text" name="email"
        {%- if account is defined %} value="{{ account.email }}"{% endif %}>

    {% if account is defined %}
        {{ errorList(account.getErrors('email')) }}
    {% endif %}

    <h3><label for="password">Password</label></h3>
    <input id="password" type="password" name="password">

    {% if account is defined %}
        {{ errorList(account.getErrors('password')) }}
    {% endif %}

    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Cheers,
Sil

Comment: Can you share the full template code you're using, Sil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't need the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` part of the form, since you don't appear to be uploading any files when saving the user.

Other than that, I'd guess that maybe you've got an Asset field on your User's field layout that set to required and you're not taking that into account on the front-end?j

Comment: Brad thank you for prompt reply, my user field layout is empty no required fields there.Not really sure what is causing this error. If I find out I will post here.

Comment: Can you enabled devMode (http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#devMode) and post the full stack trace when the "Craft\WebApp.assetUpload" error occurs?

Comment: Hi Brad, I have found that when "Upload assets on the front-end 2.0" plugin by Bob Olde Hampsink is enabled...the error appears. I have disabled it since am not using it and now everything is working as expected!

Comment: That plugin was written before front-end asset uploading was possible. Entirely not necessary now.